# Make node wait for mongoDB to start

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pm2

I use pm2 to start my database and my express node web server together. When I start them with `pm2 start all` it works fine; mongod starts before node and it can connect. But when I use `pm2 reload all` node fails to connect to the database because it tries to connect before mongod has completely initialized. This is basically the same as starting the web server and not mongod.

How can I make the web server retry connecting to mongod if it fails? There is a feature called reconnect in the node mongo driver but it only applies to loss of connection if there was a connection before.

Answer (score 0):

on error, you can call another connection function, or if you use promises, you can use a standard loop to retry.

```
//call the following in an async function
var db = null
while (db === null) {
  try {
    db = await Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb", function (err, db) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(db)
      })
    })
    //insert a sleep so you're waiting a bit to reconnect
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you envision "inserting a sleep"? I'd wrap the whole thing in a semi-recursive function calling itself using setTimeout

Comment: You can use a setTimeout  inside the initial promise